# Can I Load Google Tag Manager Twice on a Page?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Can I load two separate Google Tag Manager snippets on a web page, from two separate accounts, or will that generate an error in one of the accounts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GTM - One datalayer for multiple containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718483/gtm-one-datalayer-for-multiple-containers)

Answer (score 1):

Given that they have different `GTM-XXXX` IDs, it should work just fine.

Comment: One should probably rename the dataLayer for one of the containers (https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#renaming) lest the two datalayers interfere with each other (see for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718483/gtm-one-datalayer-for-multiple-containers).

Comment: According to Google, they don't recommend this I think? https://support.google.com/tagassistant/answer/3207128?hl=en#multiple_tags